# 500 Server Error while connecting to Stackexchange

Tags: support, login, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I am facing issue while connecting to Stack Exchange using OpenID

And here's how it's reproduced -

**Step 1**

[image]

**Step 2**

[image]

**Step3**

> provide email and password and click login.

**Error**
[image]

Is it due to the fact that the account is created today and some DB/DB's are not updated somewhere? Or is it something else?

**BROWSERS TESTED**
Internet Explorer 11
Version 11.0.9600.18665CO

Firefox
53.0.3

Comment: Which openid did you use? Which site or page did you initially visit before you got that error?

Comment: I just tried that path with my other account but I can't repro on Chrome. Do you have maybe plugins in your browser installed? Did you try another browser? Can you try another network? Maybe event another device. Are you using a VPN?
 If you can add the details to your question maybe the dev or engineer that stumbles on this might get a better idea what causes this.